# Introduction to Java programming

Tags: java

I was given an assignment to create a 3-d shape and prompt the user for the surface area and volume. I have multiple errors in my coding, but after research, I can not solve the problems.I attempted to fix the problem,but can not so I have // it out. Can anyone solve or steer me in the right direction?

The code is below:

```
//Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
//Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
//Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50,100);
//Point originOne;
//Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int width;
    int height;
    Rectangle(volume,area);
    JOptionpane.showMessageDialog("please input integer");

public static int volume;
    int vol;
    int side;
    vol =side*3;
public static int area;
    int 

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"information",
, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");
public static int surfacearea;
}
public class Rectangle {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    //constructor
    public void Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public int Point ;
    public int origin;

    // four constructors
    public Rectangle() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }
    public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    // a method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }

    // a method for computing the area of the rectangle
    public int Area() {
        //return width * height;
    }
}
```

Comment: on the main-Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
int side;--syntax error
Syntax error on token ""please input integer"", delete this token//multiples of these errors
after four constructors-point-Point cannot be resolved to a type
origin-The primitive type int of origin does not have a field x

when i try to run: i get "selection does not contain a main type"

Comment: it seems that you declare fields in main and make them public static. You cannot set static or any access modifier for local variables.

Comment: You have your `main` method around a bunch of stuff (variable declarations, etc.) that belongs in the body of the class.

Comment: I am so confused as to what you want where lol

Comment: sorry i'm new to this, trying learn as my husband is learning java. I just have alot of errors and cannot find a  way to get rid of them

Comment: @user3424877 make sure that the book/tutorial/documentation you are following to learn Java does not assume taht you know other languages and goes into basic general programming concepts at the appropiate pace like the scope of variables. Also you might want to Eclipse or some other IDEs they make compilation errors very clear.

Comment: i am using eclipse,im guessing after i attempt to run the code at the bottom window, it shows the errors?

i recieved the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field vol
 JOptionpane cannot be resolved
 Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

 at Rectangle.main(Rectangle.java:68)
Rectangle(vol,area);

Comment: I would start by learning the basics of Java before working with any GUI things. Static and non-static are very important terms you need to learn in order to understand how Java works.

Answer (score 0):

This should help slightly.. There is still a lot wrong with it. I hope my comments help a little, if you need anything else feel free to comment.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Rectangle {

    public static int area;
    public static int volume;

    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public int Point; // Uh?
    public int origin; // this isnt a Point and yet you are creating an instance of Point..
    //constructor

    /**
     * What is even the point of this????
     */
    public void Point(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

        // main needs to go in a class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width;
        int height;
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(volume,area); // actually set a variable
        //JOptionpane.showMessageDialog("please input integer"); // research this..
        int vol;
        int side; //side isnt initialized?
        vol = side*3; //this will not work
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        //JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");
    }

    // four constructors
    public Rectangle() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    public Rectangle(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }

    public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
        //This isnt calling your point method...
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    // a method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x; // Again, this is declared as an int.
        origin.y = y; // this is declared as a int.
    }

    // a method for computing the area of the rectangle
    public int Area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

Comment: "What is even the *point* of this????" heh, pun intended? I guess it should be a constructor for Rectangle.